# How to use EntityManager in Singleton DAO from Servies

Tags: java, jpa, model-view-controller, entitymanager

I'm new in JavaEE. I'm trying to make webapp using JPA with DAO and Service layer. Part of the task is not to use Spring and Hibernate. So i can use only JPA.

As i understand, Service and Dao should be a Singletones. I should get EntityManager on each database operation, and close it after. I'm using GenericDao for some operation, and EntityManager is needed in Dao, as a field. 
How to use it? How can i get entityManager in Service, start transaction in service, and pass it inside the DAO implementation?

Here's example of my DAO interface.

```
public interface GenericDAO<T> {

    void save(T entity);

    void merge(T entity);

    void delete(T entity);
    ...
}
```

I can get EntityManager in Service. In implementation all these method's will be using EntityManager. So i need it there as a field.
So how can i pass EntityManager in my DAO implementation and still make all this construction thread safe?
I don't think make inerface method like this is a good idea:

```
 void save(T entity, EntityManager entityManager);
 void merge(T entity, EntityManager entityManager);
```

Comment: If you're using Java EE, just let the container inject it, using the `@PersistenceContext` annotation, just like you would do it in Spring. No need to close it. It should be coupled with the current JTA transaction.

Answer (score 0):

EntityManager without Hibernate? What will make the ORM to it? Maybee you should use JDBC in the DAL instead of the EntityManager without Hibernate.

Answer (score 0):

Using only JPA is a good goal. Spring has been around a long time and has a very vendor specific implementation of data `repositories`. Hibernate is much closer to JPA (in my opinion), but is also quite specific. The `EntityManager` is effectively a generic DAO as you describe it. It has persist, merge, find, and delete methods, as well as many others.

In order to learn JPA a bit you can create a simple project with a simple entity and go from there. I have many such "playground" projects, but my simplest one is courtesy of [Geoffroy Warin](https://github.com/geowarin)

A main App class:

```
public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("persistence");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        try {
            EntityTransaction tx = em.getTransaction();
            tx.begin();
            User user = new User();
            em.persist(user);
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("user=" + user);

            User found = em.find(User.class, 1L);
            System.out.println("found=" + found);
        } finally {
            emf.close();
        }
    }
}
```

A simple `User` entity:

```
@Entity
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() { return id; }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "User:"+id;
    }
}
```

and a persistence.xml (goes in resources/META-INF directory):

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
  version="2.0">
  <persistence-unit name="persistence" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>model.User</class>
    <properties>
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:standalone" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

And, of course, a POM file to bring in all the dependencies.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>jpa-playground</groupId>
  <artifactId>jpa-playground</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
      <version>4.3.11.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
      <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
      <version>2.2.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Figure out how to put all this together and you can play with JPA to your hearts content. Note that is uses `Hibernate` as the `JPA` provider, but it does not use any hibernate specific constructs.

Creating a service layer is usually done with EJB's, e.g., `stateless` and `statefull` beans, and for that you need a container like `Wildfly` or `Tomcat EE`, among others. However, you can simulate them by creating a class called `ServiceLayer` and putting methods like `createUser`, `changeUserName`, `removeUser` and things like that in it. It would use the EntityManager on behalf of the application.